# How to call a generic method using super class

Tags: java

I have got some methods that are common to two subclasses so i have put them in Abstract superclass but there is one method that uses a variable with two different values so i am confused how to implement that method the code is like:

StandardMember class got this method with its own different value for **remainingCredit=30** at starting

```
public void borrowHolding(int holdingId)
            throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Hello");
        Holding tempHolding = Library.libCollection.getHolding(holdingId);
        if (Library.libCollection.getHolding(holdingId) != null) {
            if (tempHolding.isOnLoan()) {
                System.out.println("Can not be issued Currently on Load");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Can be issued");
                remainingCredit-=tempHolding.getDefaultLoanFee();
                System.out.println(getRemainingCredit());
                tempHolding.setLoanCheck(true);
                currentlyBorrowedHolding.put(holdingId, tempHolding);
                System.out.println(remainingCredit);
                System.out.println(holdingId);
            }
        }
```

PremiumMember Class got same method but the value of **remainingCredit is 45**, Whereas all the methods common to them are implemented in this AbstractMember class which implements the **Member interface**. but when i try to call these method from other class i have to initialize the object of AbstractMember in Library Class like this

```
Member member = new StandardMember();
```

which is very bad because I can not use the StandardMember object to run the PremiumMember Object's version of same method. so, either i should create new object of PremiumMember Class or i dont know what to do. but if i create two objects then this member object is being used in borrowHolding method which is basically a cascading method in Library Class which in turn calls the borrowHolding method in Member Interface:

```
public void borrowHolding(int holdingId) throws InsufficientCreditException, MultipleBorrowingException {
        if(libCollection.holdingMap==null){
            System.out.println("Collection is Empty");
        }
        if(libCollection.holdingMap.containsKey(holdingId))
        member.borrowHolding(holdingId);        
    }
```

the problem is i can not create two objects because at runtime i can only call one method. so help me out how to implement this method in Abstract class so that program will detect the difference that which object it should create.

Comment: Are you saying that `borrowHolding()` is _not_ defined in `AbstractMember` although it has the same code for both subclasses? If yes, why?

Comment: actually this method is defined in different interface called borrower and another interface Member extends Borrower interface and then in AbstractMember class i want write the implementation for this method which furtheron can be used by two subclasses of AbstractMember that is PremiumMember and StandardMember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have a `Member` abstract class with a field `remainingCredit` which has to be `30` in one subclass and `45` in another.

Use a protected constructor.

```
public abstract class Member {

    private int remainingCredit;
    // Other members
    // getters and setters

    protected Member(String memId, String memName, int remainingCredit) {
        this.memId = memId;
        this.memName = memName;
        this.remainingCredit = remainingCredit;
    }
}

public StandardMember extends Member {

    public StandardMember(String memId, String memName) {
        super(memId, memName, 30);
    }
}

public PremiumMember extends Member {

    public PremiumMember(String memId, String memName) {
        super(memId, memName, 45);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i could have done that but when the objects of Member Class are created in starting then it is created using two parameters like this:
 public AbstractMember(String memId, String memName) {
  this.memberId = memId;
  this.fullName = memName;
 } so how to pass this remainingCredit to it

Comment: @monty: by adding a third parameter.

Comment: At the time when Member is created only two parameters are passed i show you the flow model.addMember(new StandardMember(STANDARD_MEMBER_ID,
    STANDARD_MEMBER_NAME));public StandardMember(String memId, String memName) {
  super(memId, memName);
  this.remainingCredit = 30;
 }public AbstractMember(String memId, String memName) {
  this.memberId = memId;
  this.fullName = memName;
 } so tell me how to add or where to add this third parameter

Comment: but it is forced that when the member object is created only these two parameters should be passed the StandardMember or PremiumMember should be initialized on the bases on which object is created...

Comment: @monty: In my code, StandardMember and PremiumMember classes have constructors with only two parameters. Is that not what you want?

Comment: but is not that true that no. of arugments a subclass constructor receives then it should call the super constructor that have same no of arguments